# How to Create a Dynamic Power BI Label Based On Multiple Potential Drill-Through Options

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need some help creating a custom Power BI Label [Card Visual]. I have a summary page and a detail page I want to drill-through too. There are three Team Charts on the summary tab that contain a simple Manager-Employee hierarchy. (Sales Team, Distribution Team, and Service Team).

Each record in the detail has a Sales Manager/Employee, Distribution Manager/Employee, and Service Manager/Employee. So I was easily able to set up a drill-through to the detail page for each of my Manager/Employee charts. However, I cannot create a custom label.

When I drill-through on Sales Manager chart, I want the label on the detail page to say "Sales Manager [Name] Detail". When I drill-though on the Service Employee I want the detail page to say "Service Employee [Name] Detail."

Is it possible to create such a dynamic label?

I could theoretically create a detail page for each Team. This would balloon to 6 detail tabs (Sales Manager Detail, Sales Employee Detail, Dist. Manager Detail, Dist. Employee Detail, Service Manager Detail, Service Employee Detail)

I would also need to create 6 label measures.

```
Sales Manager Label = 
   var selectedSalesManager = SELECTEDVALUE('Detail'[SalesManager]) 
    return IF(ISBLANK(selectedSalesManager), 
              "All Managers", 
               selectedSalesManager & "'s Team Detail")
```

I'm really hoping there is a way to achieve what I'm after, and I appreciate everyone's help and insight!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You need to look at ISFILTERED() in DAX.
for example:

```
Manager Label = 
var SalesManager = SELECTEDVALUE('Detail'[SalesManager])
var DistributionManager = SELECTEDVALUE('Detail'[DistributionManager ])

return

IF(ISFILTERED('Detail'[SalesManager]),
     SalesManager & "'s Team Detail",
        IF(ISFILTERED('Detail'[DistributionManager ]),
             DistributionManager & "'s Team Detail")
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly what I needed. Now, is there a way where I can put a special message for when multiple selections are made in the filter pane?

Comment: My pleasure. Hasonefilter() is the function that you need. This function returns true when the specified table or column has one and only one value resulting from direct filter(s). You can use it in IF function and get the result in the same Card.